# How to get Görli test ETH?

Tags: testnets, polygon, opensea, faucets, goerli

I want to do some *"buy tests"* on OpenSea testnet, and it turns out that I need some ETH on the *"mumbai" testnet of Polygon!!* [The official Polygon Faucet](https://faucet.polygon.technology/) doesn't provide testnet ETH, of course!
but, there's a bridge on the [*"wallet-dev" on Polygon*](https://wallet-dev.polygon.technology/bridge) that *only* bridges the *"Goerly chain testnet ETH"* onto the Polygon testnet! I've ended up with the followings:

- MetaMask introduced a broken faucet at https://goerli-faucet.slock.it/, a meaningful death is better than a meaningless life!
- Googling revealed another useless and [stupid one](https://goerli-faucet.mudit.blog/) that not only requires you to be famous on the selective social media to authorize you, but also always complains that there's not enough funds!! I don't neither use Facebook nor Twitter, but I've made accounts on those to get some testnet ETH! At the end, it doesn't accept the Facebook link at all! (Facebook has updated it's endpoints, but it doesn't adapt!), and for the Twitter, it says that the account needs to have some followers and twits and to be old enough to be accepted! (I've tried with multiple permissible Tweeter accounts at various times to no avail!)

*It's a huge shame and a terrible experience for such a trivial and yet fundamental matter!* I've also found out that other Ethereum testnets do suffer from this issue! I think this *unacceptable disgrace* is on the Ethereum that doesn't have provided such a facility!

I've been wandering around for hours and hours finding some Görli testnet ETH to no avails! How can I get some?! Or simply how to get ETH on Mumbai testnet?

Comment: I have the same exact problem. Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to only test any contracts you develop on Rinkeby testnet, even if you're developing smart contracts for L2s. Rinkeby happens to be much more supported than any of the other testnets, and it's so much easier to find its faucets. Some examples are:

https://faucet.rinkeby.io

https://faucet.metamask.io

https://faucets.chain.link/rinkeby

**Update:** Rinkeby testnet has been recently deprecated. You should be using Goerli from this point on. You could use the following faucet to get Goerli ETH:

https://goerlifaucet.com

Comment: Thanks for the reply; Rinkeby is an Ethereum testnet, but Mumbai is a Polygon testnet; further more, for a test, I want ETH on Mumbai, and AFASIK, I can only bridge ETH from Goerli network onto the Mumbai! While the stupid Goerli faucet (linked in OP), rejects posts from new Tweeter accounts (my case!) Thus I should find an old Tweeter account or grow my own's, which is not practical in a short time!!

Comment: Polygon is completely EVM-compatible, just like both Rinkeby and Mumbai. That's why I suggested sticking to Rinkeby and not bothering with Mumbai.

Comment: Sorry to hear about the struggle to get testETH, what a headache! https://goerlifaucet.com/ is Alchemy's faucet and gives free testETH reliably (you can get more daily if you need). Quick note - due to the Ethereum merge, Rinkeby, Ropsten, and Kovan have been deprecated. Only Goerli is supported for Ethereum testnets.